# ISCSI MPIO Extra devices, and is there meant to be an mpath0-part2?

Tags: iscsi, proxmox, synology, mpio

I am trying to learn more about ISCSI and Multipath (MPIO) setup on a proxmox system. I thought I had everything working, but have that terrible spidey sense that something is incorrectly configured, am seeing no speed improvements, and even see an oddity "mpath0-part1" but no "mpath0-part2" as I would have expected from the outset.

High level topology:
I have a single LUN setup on my NAS with a single target accepting multiple connections on all (both) nic interfaces via an ISCSI target. (Is this even correct or should it be two iscsi targets?) On the initiator side, two ifaces setup, each with an assigned ip.

lsblk give me: (sdg and sdf)

```
NAME                                     MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                        8:0    0 279.4G  0 disk
├─sda1                                     8:1    0  1007K  0 part
├─sda2                                     8:2    0   512M  0 part
└─sda3                                     8:3    0 278.9G  0 part
  ├─pve-swap                             253:0    0    30G  0 lvm
  └─pve-root                             253:1    0  69.5G  0 lvm   /
sdb                                        8:16   0 279.4G  0 disk
└─sdb1                                     8:17   0 279.4G  0 part
sdc                                        8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sdc1                                     8:33   0 517.7M  0 part
├─sdc2                                     8:34   0 929.5G  0 part
└─sdc4                                     8:36   0   500M  0 part
sdd                                        8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdd1                                     8:49   0 931.5G  0 part
sde                                        8:64   0   7.8T  0 disk
└─sde1                                     8:65   0   7.8T  0 part
sdf                                        8:80   0   7.8T  0 disk
├─sdf1                                     8:81   0   7.8T  0 part
└─mpath0                                 253:2    0   7.8T  0 mpath
  └─mpath0-part1                         253:3    0   7.8T  0 part
    ├─iscsi_volumegroup-vm--100--disk--0 253:4    0   250G  0 lvm
    └─iscsi_volumegroup-vm--102--disk--2 253:5    0   250G  0 lvm
sdg                                        8:96   0   7.8T  0 disk
├─sdg1                                     8:97   0   7.8T  0 part
└─mpath0                                 253:2    0   7.8T  0 mpath
  └─mpath0-part1                         253:3    0   7.8T  0 part
    ├─iscsi_volumegroup-vm--100--disk--0 253:4    0   250G  0 lvm
    └─iscsi_volumegroup-vm--102--disk--2 253:5    0   250G  0 lvm
sdh                                        8:112  0   7.8T  0 disk
└─sdh1                                     8:113  0   7.8T  0 part
sr0                                       11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
nvme0n1                                  259:0    0   477G  0 disk
└─nvme0n1p1                              259:1    0   477G  0 part
nvme1n1                                  259:2    0   477G  0 disk
└─nvme1n1p1                              259:3    0   477G  0 part  [SWAP]
```

multipath -ll

```
mpath0 (long_jibberish_like_ 6840d4606db20ad5) dm-2 SYNOLOGY,iSCSI Storage
size=7.8T features='0' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=50 status=active
  |- 10:0:0:1 sdg 8:96  active ready running
  `- 8:0:0:1  sdf 8:80  active ready running
```

Through trying to get this working, I also appear to have ended up with additional sde, sdh devices, and not sure if sdf1 and sdg1 should be present...

There is no hyper critical stuff on any of these drives, as I am still in a learning phase, my important docs (etc) are stored elsewhere.

- Is there meant to be a mpath0-part2?
- What's up with sdf1, and sdg1?
- What's up with sde, and sdh?